# Android: Close App if AsyncTask initialisation (file download) fails

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Every time user launch the App, some initialisation phase occurs involving downloading file from web in `AsyncTask`. I need to monitor situation of launching the App while connection problems and handle it:

1. If the download started but not finished - Wait 3 seconds maybe in the while the download will finish - So then resume to the initialisation process.
2. If after the extra 3 seconds the download not finished - close the App.
3. If from the beginning the download not started - Close the App.

What I did:

```
public class Initialisation extends Activity {

    public boolean isDownloadStarted = false;
    public boolean isDownloadFinished = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
        initFoo1();
        …
        new DownloadAsyncTask.execute();  //for the sake of simplicity assume it 
                                            takes “zero time” so if all OK it 
                                            should be ready in next line check
        ...
        initFooN();
        if (isDownloadFinished) {
            //continue regular
        }
        //if download started and not finished maybe it’s just slow connection
        //give 3 more seconds to succeed 
        else if (isDownloadStarted == true && isDownloadFinished == false) {
            showProgressSpinner();
            new SleepAsyncTask.execute();
        }
        //if download not started - Connection error - close App now
        else if (!isDownloadStarted) {
            exitProcess();
        }
    }

    public class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        public void doInBackground(Void… params) {
            isDownloadStarted = true;
            fooDownloadFile();   
            isDownloadFinished = true;
        }
    }

    public class SleepAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        public void doInBackground(Void… params) {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (isDownloadFinished) {
                dismissProgressSpinner();
                //TODO: Do nothing - Should be continue regular?
            }
            //if even after 3 more seconds the download not finished - close the App
            else {
                exitProcess();
            }
        }
    }

    public void exitProcess() {
        //TODO: Is it the right way?
        this.finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

My questions are regarding the TODO's and in overall - Is this approach will succeed and this is a good way handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You share boolean variables between 2 threads - some synchronization should be provided when accessing them. Theoretically, the AsyncTask's thread makes the copies of your boolean values and such situation may lead to unexpected meeting or not meeting the conditions in your `if` statements.
   In your case, the `volatile` keyword should be helpful. You can read more about it here(http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml).
2. Why do you use AsyncTask actually? One of the major problems with AsyncTasks is a cancelation of their jobs. Secondly, they often cause memory leaks in the applications. I suggest employing [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to do your download job.
3. By invoking `System.exit(0)` you tell the VM to explicitly restart your process. Is this desirable behaviour?
4. If after the extra 3 seconds the download not finished - close the App.

Well, I am not sure whether you're aware of that but from Android HONEYCOMB the AsyncTasks execute sequentially when not explicitly told to run in parallel manner (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html - Order of execution).

Here is the example of IntentService usage
https://github.com/dawidgdanski/Bakery . To handle the logic of Notifying application to exit after 3 seconds if download does not succeed, use [Handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)). For communication purpouses between IntentService and your Activity use [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Flow:

1. Start activity. Invoke Handler's.postDelayed() method. Start Service. Register Broadcast Receiver to handle the broadcast from service once the download job is finished.
2. When the download finishes before the awaiting timeout, [remove all callbacks from Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages(java.lang.Object))
3. Otherwise call `finish()` method in the timeout Runnable.

Hope that helps somehow.

Comment: Thanks, regarding your comment "AsyncTasks execute sequentially" is this means that if I stay with AsyncTasks all my logic incorrect? (open task taht sleeps=waiting for download...)?

Comment: Yes, the second task always executes after downloading task. Relying on AsyncTasks does not make sense in your case imo. You can always enable the tasks to run concurrently but synchronization between them is more difficult and adds unnecessary bunch of code.

Comment: Thanks, How to enable? (There is a lot of code here before me and I'm not sure if it's smart to rewrite it all)

Comment: executeOnExecutor() method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Params...)